# $f(1)+f(-1)=0$ prove $f(x)$ does not divide $x^n -1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

> Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb Z[x]$ satisfying $f(1)+f(-1)=0$.  Prove that $f(x)$ does not divide $x^n-1$ for any positive integer $n$.

with $f(1)+f(-1)=0$ it means sum of all even terms is $0;$ how is that related to divisibility to $x^n -1$? I can't figure out and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We know that $X^n-1$ factorizes into irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as below $$X^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(X)$$

Where $\Phi_d(X)$ is the $d^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial. Since $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ then
if we assume $f\mid X^n-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ then it must be one of the irreducible cyclotomic polynomials since $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a $\mathrm{UFD}$. Let $f=\Phi_d$ for some $d\mid n$. Then we need to prove that $\Phi_d(1)+\Phi_d(-1)\neq0$ to reach a contradiction.

If $d=2^mr$ with $\gcd(2,r)=1$ and $m\geq2$, then $\Phi_d(X)=\Phi_{2r}(X^{2^{m-1}})$. Hence in this case $\Phi_d(1)=\Phi_d(-1)$ and therefore the equation $\Phi_d(1)+\Phi_d(-1)=0$ would imply $\Phi_d(1)=0$ but this is a contradiction since $1$ is not a root of $\Phi_d(X)$.

If $d=p^k$ for some prime $p$ then $$\Phi_d(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}X^{ip^{k-1}}$$

Then in this case one can easily verify that $\Phi_d(1)+\Phi_d(-1)\neq0$.

If $d$ is not a power of a prime then it's well known that $\Phi_d(1)=1$. Then the equation $\Phi_d(1)+\Phi_d(-1)=0$ would imply $\Phi_d(-1)=-1$.

We are left with two cases $d=2k$ with $\gcd(2,k)=1$ and $d$ odd and not a power of a prime. For the first case we know that $\Phi_d(X)=\Phi_k(-X)$. Hence $$-1=\Phi_d(-1)=\Phi_k(1)$$ A contradiction since $\Phi_k(1)$ is either $1$ when $k$ is not a power of a prime or $q$ when $r=q^l$ for a prime $q$.

For the last case, when $d$ is odd, we have $\Phi_{2d}(1)=\Phi_d(-1)=-1$. Again a contradiction as we observed before.

We are done!

**In this proof we have used lots of properties of a cyclotomic polynomial. For reference check this link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial**

Comment: roots of x^n -1 must be on the unit circle in complex plane; for f(x) to divide x^n -1 its roots must be a subset of the unit circle with conjugates pairs included. How does that contradict f(1) +f (-1) =0? it doesn't look so obvious to me

Comment: Yeah it's not obvious. I'm also trying to prove all cases. I've posted the proof for one case when $d$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: If $n$ is odd so are all its factors $d$. Because $\Phi_1(-1)=-2$ and $(-1)^n-1=-2$ it follows by induction from
$$-2=(-1)^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(-1)$$ that for all odd $n>1$ we have $\Phi_n(-1)=1$.

Comment: If $d=2r$, $r$ odd, then $\Phi_d(x)=\Phi_r(-x)$, and $\Phi_d(1)+\Phi_d(-1)=\Phi_r(1)+\Phi_r(-1)\neq0$.

Comment: Now proved for all cases.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen wonderful and simple argument for the case when $d$ is odd and $n$ is odd.